# update radio buttons after each record iteration through cursor

Tags: android, radio-group

I have three radio buttons and a method that each time i click on a Button Next.  The next record will be displayed using a setonclickListener. 
The goal is clear all the radio buttons after each record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is very simple I was trying to change the value using setChecked(false); for each radio button but what this did was every time I clicked on the button it was cleared. The answer that I was looking for was `clearCheck()` of RadioGroup class, this acts as a reset.